# how to get environment variable value in Android.mk?

Tags: android, makefile

Any possibility to get environment variable value inside Android.mk?

For example

```
#export MYBASEDIR=/home/whoami/base
```

And, inside Android.mk How to get MYBASEDIR value ?

Bear with me for very basic question.

Comment: Have you tried `$(MYBASEDIR)` to access it?

Answer (score 11):

All environment variables are imported by make as make macros automatically.

So, just use `$(MYBASEDIR)` in the makefile.